# i want to communicate with 'TestEquity1000' temperature chamber by using 'pyserial'

Tags: python-3.x

i want to set and get temperature of serial device (testequity1000) by using pyserial but not able to communicate. 
cable used RS232
python 3.7

```
import serial
port = 'COM20'
```

`   serial_comunication = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

```
answer = serial_comunication.read(400)

print(answer)
NEW_TEMPERATURE=45
set_temp=serial_comunication.write(b'NEW_TEMPERATURE')
print(set_temp)
abc=serial_comunication.close()
print(abc)
results:
b''
15
None
can't understand these result
```

Answer (score 0):

Your device seems to be able to communicate on the RS232 bus but you have to use Modbus instead of the raw serial.

Quoting from the [manual](https://www.testequity.com/UserFiles/documents/pdfs/1007Hman.pdf):

> The F4 Temperature Controller has an RS-232C interface. A DB-9
> connector is located on the rear panel. It is wired to accommodate a
> null-modem cable. To communicate with the controller from a PC, you
> need to run software that uses the Modbus RTU protocol. Each
> controller function has a “register” number which can be read or
> written to (when applicable). These registers are listed Chapter Seven
> of the [“Series F4 User’s Manual”](https://www.testequity.com/UserFiles/documents/pdfs/F4_Controller.pdf). RS-232C Modbus programming resources
> and LabVIEW drivers can be downloaded from
> http://chamber.testequity.com/rs232.html
>
> Common Modbus Registers
>
> -Actual chamber temperature reading is register 100 (Input 1 Value).
>
> -Actual chamber humidity reading is register 104 (Input 2 Value).
>
> -Static temperature set point is register 300 (Set Point 1).
>
> -Static humidity set point is register 319 (Set Point 2). •
>
> -Temperature set point during a profile is register 4122 (Set Point 1, Current Profile Status).
>
> -Humidity set point during a profile is register 4123 (Set Point 2, Current Profile Status).
>
> -Decimal points are implied. For example, 1005 is actually 100.5 and -230 is -23.0.

Based on these details you can use [*pymodbus*](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus) instead. A good starting point is [this example](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/master/examples/common/synchronous_client.py).

You can install the package with: `pip install pymodbus`

So, if you want to read the *Actual Chamber Temperature* you need to write something similar to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Pymodbus Synchronous Client Examples

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# import the various server implementations
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# configure the client logging
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
import logging
FORMAT = ('%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)-15s '
          '%(levelname)-8s %(module)-15s:%(lineno)-8s %(message)s')
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

UNIT = 0x1

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# choose the client you want
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------#
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='COM20', timeout=1, baudrate=19200)
client.connect()

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# example requests
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
rr = client.read_holding_registers(100, 1, unit=UNIT) #Actual chamber temperature reading
print(rr.registers[0])

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# close the client
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
client.close()
```

You might need to change the default baudrate (according to the manual 19200) and/or the Modbus UNIT ID (UNIT 1 is the default value).

Answer (score 0):

Hello I actually just finished using a little something in python. TestEquity chamber for the RS-232 you need to use modbus RTU protocol.

I'm using [minimalmodbus](https://pypi.org/project/minimalmodbus/). The other thing is that you need to make sure that you are using a null modem Tx and Rx need to be swapped in the DB9 connector.

Check the baudrate and slave address in setup, communications.

My code is here:

```
import minimalmodbus

 TE1007C = minimalmodbus.Instrument("COM5", 1)
 # Set baudrate
 TE1007C.serial.baudrate = 9600
 temp = TE1007C.read_register(100, 1, signed=True)
 print(temp)
```

To set a temperature use write_register(). There are other registers that can be use.